# Подсчет числа процессов с заданным именем

Tags: linux, c

Помогите написать программу, которая должна осуществлять поиск и подсчет числа процессов по имени (например: "my-proc").

Я так понял:

1. Пройтись по каталогам в каталоге "/proc/".
2. В каждом из них прочесть файл "comm" и сравнить его с именем процесса которое ищем.

п.с. Как реализовать на Си?

Comment: А какие сложности ? `opendir(); while(readdir()) { open(); read(); if(memcmp()) n++; close(); } printf n;`

Comment: @Mike Более подробно никак? =)

Comment: Нет, иначе это уже будет работа за спрашивающего, что на SO не приветствуется. И собственно все требуемые функции перечислены, остается завести несколько переменных, посмотреть в гугле как эти функции используются

Comment: @Mike Все зашибись, прошел задание, по сути, вашим методом...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И так, прошел данное задание методом используя opendir fopen и т.д.

Но вот какое решение мне показали:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    system("pidof -c genenv | wc -w");
}
```

**Кто то может объяснить, что происходит?**

*п.с. genenv - имя процесса, количество которых нужно подсчитать*

Comment: Читайте man pidof и man wc. / Коротко, `pidof -c NAME` (например `pidof -c bash`) выведет список PID процессов с таким именем. Команда `wc -w` подсчитает количество слов в этом списке

Answer (score 2):

Аналогично первому ответу:

```
ps ax | grep my-proc | wc -l
```

ps - выдаёт список ВСЕХ процессорв
grep - фильтрует по заданному имени
wc - считает сколько строк получиось

Comment: Находит один процесс ping, хотя он не запущен: ps ax | grep ping | wc -l 1